# iPhone Socket Server won't stop when peers are alive

Tags: xcode, sockets

i have some problems using sockets for my iPhone app. I hope someone can help me.

The problem i have is the situation, when i want to close my server socket, that is accepting sockets for a connection. I have a list of sockets made through accept. When i want to stop the server i first go through the list and close all sockets before i close the server. But that does not work. When i want to start the server again i get the message "Address already in use". I use CFSocketRef Objects to handle the sockets. The code is pretty huge, so i show just some snippets handling them.

First i start the server

```
Function: StartServer
...
//Create Server Socket
socket = CFSocketCreate(nil, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, 
         kCFSocketAcceptCallBack, socketServerRunLoopCallBack, &socketContext);
...
//Set Socket to RunLoop for Accept
runLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent();
socketRunLoop = CFSocketCreateRunLoopSource(nil, socket, 0);
CFRunLoopAddSource(runLoop, socketRunLoop, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
```

Now the server waits for connections to clients. this will be made by the RunLoop and the CallBack

```
Function: CreateSocketFromPeer
...
//socket is NOT the same reference than above. This reference
//is in an independent instance.
socket = CFSocketCreateWithNative(nil, theSocketNative, kCFSocketReadCallBack, 
         socketRunLoopCallBack, &socketContext);
//theSocketNative is the socket handle that the server got from the CallBack
socketNative = theSocketNative;
```

Now the server wants to be closed. But the socket created by the server for the peer is still open. So the server is trying to close it

```
Function: StopServer
...
//Stop the RunLoop
CFRunLoopRemoveSource(runLoop, socketRunLoop, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
CFRunLoopSourceInvalidate(socketRunLoop);
CFRelease(socketRunLoop);
socketRunLoop = nil;
//disconnect any peer made by the servers accept CallBack
for (GTSocket *entry in connections)
    [entry disconnect];
//stop now the server
CFSocketInvalidate(socket);
CFRelease(socket);
socket = nil;
socketNative = -1;
```

the server did closed using the disconnect function of the socket handling the peer.

```
Function: Disconnect
CFSocketInvalidate(socket);
CFRelease(socket);
socket = nil;
socketNative = -1;
```

Still the Server won't stop correctly even when i invalidate the socket made by CFSocketCreateWithNative... Can someone help me?

EDIT

The situation is getting worse.

I tested some ideas i got but nothing seems to help. The following should ever be successful. but not in my case

in the callback of my socket server i wrote following

```
static void socketServerRunLoopCallBack(CFSocketRef s, CFSocketCallBackType type, CFDataRef address, const void *data, void *info) {
    if (type == kCFSocketAcceptCallBack) {
        close(*(CFSocketNativeHandle *)data);
    }
}
```

this should close the peer immediately but still if i close and reopen the socket server i get "Address already in use"

I simplified my code extracting anything unnecessary for the connection but i still cannot close peers when i want to close the server socket.